# Font awesome black rectangle

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome, codekit

Trying to implement font awesome into a web project, but the output is a 1px solid border rectangle. I am using Sass with Codekit and I have checked my paths accordingly. see below

**1. main.scss**

```
 @import 'base/font-awesome/font-awesome.scss';
```

**2. variables.scss**

```
$fa-font-path: "../font-awesome/fonts" !default;
```

**3. Folder structure**

[image]

**4. Main.css output**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url("font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0");
  src: url("font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0") format("embedded-opentype"),  
  url("font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0") format("woff"),
  url("font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0") format("truetype"), 
  url("font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; 
}
```

**5. HTML**

```
 <i class="fa-twitter"></i>
```

What am I doing wrong? I have checked the docs and have looked at other solutions on stackoverflow but it doesn't seem to be working. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the HTML?

Comment: What browser/version are you using to test?

Comment: Just added it. Good enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the fa class, so the font-awesome font is not being actually used but other one. Do it like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
```

Comment: Wow I missed that little detail. Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention, the square you are seeing is because the character code doesn't have a character representation out of the font. Many fonts work like this, they set up a css class just for setting up the font name, so watch out other fonts like that.